# Auto complete chrome trazendo campos errados como login

Tags: html, formulário, navegador-de-internet, autocompletar

Estou com um problema onde tenho um formulário de cadastro. Ao realizar o cadastro o navegador pergunta se ele quer salvar o  usuário e senha, o problema é que ele salva um campo nada ver como usuário mas a senha ele grava corretamente. Meu formulário esta assim:

```
<form id="form_cadastro" autocomplete="off">
   <div id="passo1">
     <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="validate" />
   </div>
   <div id="passo2">
     <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" />
   </div>
   <div id="passo3">
     <input name="endereco" id="endereco" type="text" />
     <input name="complemento" id="complemento" type="text" />
   </div>
   <div id="passo4">
     <input name="senha" id="senha" type="password" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Mas ao dar um `submit` via `$.post` JQuery no formulário, e redirecinando a página o navegador está salvando(pedindo pra salvar) o valor do campo `complemento(do endereço)` como usário! Assim quando o usuário vai para a tela de login o `Auto complete/Auto Fill` do Navegador traz no campo usuario (que é o email) o valor do campo complemento:

```
<form id="form_cadastro" autocomplete="off">
     <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="validate" /> // Autocomplete vindo o complemento(do endereço)
     <input name="senha" id="senha" type="password" />
</form>
```

Teria algum modo de resolver isso de uma maneira que não use muita gambiarra?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill tenta usar o autocomplete attribute no input

Comment: @RovannLinhalis isso nunca funcionou comigo :P.

Comment: Coloca o input email acima do input senha (no lugar do complemento) e veja que bicho vai dar.

Comment: Faz sentido essa dae @LeoCaracciolo rsrs

Comment: Chrome com login e senha é irritante, além de dar aquela indesejavel amarelada no campo de uma pagina que não é dele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, quando o navegador pergunta se ele quer salvar o usuário e senha E VOCÊ ACEITA, **não sei porque**, o Chrome assume que o input imediatamente acima do input senha seja o do usuario.

Basta verificar nestes dois exemplos que postei no meu servidor

[complemento acima da senha](http://kithomepage.com/sos/senha.php)

[email acima da senha](http://kithomepage.com/sos/senha1.php)

e veja que meu comentário, embora pareça hilário, tem fundamento.

> OBS: os HTML utilizados são os do autor da pergunta.

**Resta claro que você teria que ter feito login e senha no site dos exemplos e aceitar salvar quando o Chrome perguntar.**

A titulo de teste faça [login aqui](http://kithomepage.com/sos/loginSessionStorage.html) aceite salvar e depois acesse os exemplos

- OBS: após ter feito login e aceitar , pode fechar a pagina redirecionada que faz parte de uma resposta de outro post.

---

---

> texto traduzido pelo google do post abaixo indicado" -> Acabei de descobrir que, se você tiver um nome de usuário e uma senha lembrados para um site, a versão atual do Chrome irá preencher automaticamente seu nome de usuário / endereço de e-mail no campo antes de qualquer type=passwordcampo. Não se importa com o chamado do campo - **apenas assume o campo antes de a senha ser seu nome de usuário**."

### Mais sobre esse problema veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: "matou a cobra e mostrou o pau kkk", cara eu me pergunto porque a unica coisa que se encontra na internet é falando sobre o `autocomplete="off"` sendo que nem funciona essa bagaça. Fiz o teste aqui e deu certinho sua teoria. É uma pena os navegadores não terem uma solução mais "`cross-browser`" pra esse problema chato.